# Another File Upload connection timeout ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, upload, connection-reset

I'm build an application with ASP.Net MVC 5. When uploading a big file, well not that big (200MB), the browser gives me a "Connection Reset" error. The hosting is done by Godaddy (Deluxe - shared hosting plan).

I searched countless forums and of course here and the answer is almost always the same:

Add to system.web:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="999999"/>
```

And/or Add to system.webServer:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="32767" maxQueryString="32767" maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

It must be place in Web.config (at root not the one in views folder).

I know that `maxRequestLenght` and `maxAllowedContentLenght` are not the same units (byte vs kilobyte). So I tried different conbinaision, same number, different one...

I also tried calling GoDaddy and ask them if it could be on thier end, they said, no, but they told me that I could add a ".user.ini" file at the root directory containing something like:

```
upload_max_filesize=2000M
memory_limit=128M
max_execution_time=99999
post_max_size=2000M
max_input_time=99999
```

That did not work either...

Here is code, if you need the controller, just ask, but since there is a timeout on the browser, I don't see the point:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSingleTune", "Upload", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resource.SampleLabel, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" multiple="multiple" data-val="true" data-val-required="@Resource.ImageRequiredErrorMessage" id="SingleTuneViewModel_Sample" name="SingleTuneViewModel.Sample" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SingleTuneViewModel.Sample, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="@Resource.CreateButton" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    }
```

Model:

```
public class SingleTuneViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Album")]
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tune")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Tune { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Sample")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Sample { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

}
```

Can Someone help, I'm out of ideas and it seems so simple. Is my only option to use "chunk" ?

Comment: It says timeout in the title, but it is really a "connection reset" error page that appears in the broswer

Comment: is it working at local or working on live with small sized files ?

Comment: it is working local and also working with small sized files